AWS Redshift Cluster: Defer maintenance window not getting disabled
I have created one AWS Redshift cluster and it not allowing me to Defer maintenance window.
Screenshot
What is stopping me from doing this? I am in same region as well.
I even logged out from the AWS account and tried again but the same issue is still there.

I think the error message is saying that you didn't change any settings, the 'Defer' option must already be disabled. If you wish to tell it to Defer, then you should click 'Enable'. Or are you saying that you cannot click the Enabled button? Just to explain... 'Defer' means "delay", so if you do NOT want a maintenance window, then choose Enabled.
